# Last kernel not loading

Tags: kernel

Hello I have the latest vesion of Ubuntu Studio and madenun upgrade for the latest stable lowlatency kernel versions 4.15.0-58, 60 and 64... nome of them loads, they all freeze when booting and all of them fail... When they start loading all of them give the same erro like this One of the 64 version when loading the recovery mode, I'll leave here the screen photo... With normal and recovery mode...
By the way. I have an ASUS modelo X552MJ with the latest BIOS instalei. And the rest of the last messages in recovery mode (OS doesn't have ASPM control)
But the version 4.15.0-52 loads beyond it gives the same errors it starts... Someone Over there to help me?
And yes I've already tried every single options in BIOS...
Thanks for your time...

Sorry but they are not leting me do this post with images... Need 10points of reputation... ☹️

Comment: The latest release of Ubuntu Studio is 19.04 and uses kernel 5.0, so I'm betting you are using 18.04 without HWE (ie. 4.15 kernel). Can you please confirm you are using 18.04 (it's two behind latest).  Have you added the extended support if you are indeed using 18.04 (it was not LTS on Ubuntu Studio), and links to your images stored somewhere would have worked.